# Formally smooth fiberwise criterion over a DVR

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

**Question**

> Let $f: X \to S$ be a flat morphism of schemes where
>
> 1. $S$ is a DVR with algebraically closed residue field,
> 2. special fiber is smooth,
> 3. and generic fiber is formally smooth
>
> Is $f$ a formally smooth morphism?

If the above is not true in general, is there are an extra condition that can be imposed that $f$ is formally smooth?

**Motivation**

I am trying to understand the proof of Proposition 5.2. in Yoshida's paper *On non-abelian Lubin-Tate theory via vanishing cycles* [Link](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0404375). To set up some notations let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and $W$ be the ring of integers of the completion of the maximal unramified extension of $K$. Now let $Y$ be the spectrum of the representing algebra of a moduli functor defined by

$\{$ Complete Noetherian Local $W$-algebra with residue field isomorphic to that of $W$ }

to

$\{$ Deformations of formal $\mathcal{O}_K$-module of height $n$ over the residue field of $W$ with Drinfeld level $\mathfrak{p}$-structure $\}$

Then $X$ is obtained by first blowing up $Y$ at the unique closed point, pick an affine cover of the blow-up, complete along the exceptional divisor, and invert some equations, and pick a closed subscheme that eventually becomes normalization. I am being unprecise because it will take too much to describe the process.

Just in case it helps, $X$ is the spectrum of

$$ W_n[V_1,\ldots, V_n] \left [ \frac{1}{V_n} \right ][[X_n]]/(\omega_n - V_n X_n, u \cdot \prod_{a \in k^n \backslash \{ 0 \}} P_a - V_n^{q^n-1}) $$

where $k$ is the residue field of $K$, $P_a$ is a power series induced from the universal deformation of the moduli functor mentioned above. I apologize for being imprecise here also. Here $W_n$ is the ring of integers of $K(\omega_n)$ where $\omega_n=\omega^{1/(q^n-1)}$.

And our $S = \mathrm{Spec}~W_n$.

I think I can find an argument if $X$ is a spectrum of a local ring, but as of right now, I feel like the above is not a local ring.

Comment: Is your morphism $f$ not locally of finite type?

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar I don't think so. It is a quotient of some formal power series ring with only two equations.